# Python 3 install location

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 . Where is the python 3 installation directory ?
Running "whereis python3" in terminal gives me:

> python3: /usr/bin/python3.5m-config  /usr/bin/python3 
>   /usr/bin/python3.5m
>  /usr/bin/python3.5-config  /usr/bin/python3.5 
>   /usr/lib/python3
>   /usr/lib/python3.5  /etc/python3  /etc/python3.5
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.5
>    /usr/include/python3.5m 
>   /usr/include/python3.5
>   /usr/share/python3 
>   /usr/share/man/man1/python3.1.gz

Also where is the intrepreter i.e the python 3 executable ? And how would I add this path to Pycharm ?

Comment: Try `which python3`

Comment: The executable is `/usr/bin/python3`.

Comment: @abarnert Thanks and where are the other files of python 3 located ? and if a program asks for directory of python 3 should I give the directory as "/usr/bin/python3" ?

Comment: No. I'm not sure what PyCharm means by "installation directory", but it's definitely not `/usr/bin/python3`; that's not even a directory. (When I've used PyCharm, both on Ubuntu and on macOS, it's always given me a list of all local installed Pythons, and the only time I've had to add one manually, it's because I had a local build under some `~/src` directory.) But I'm sure it's in their docs. Configuring for a standard Ubuntu package can't be an uncommon thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can try this :

`which python3`

Comment: running that gives me "/usr/bin/python3" but that is not a directory, it is a "link to executable"

Comment: Maybe this link will help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/262063/how-to-find-python-installation-directory-on-ubuntu

Comment: @sshashank So "/usr/bin/python3" is the path of executable and "/usr/lib/python3" is the actual directory ? So if a program asks for python directory, where should I point it to ?

Comment: @Emerdan if you type python3 in terminal it will show python 3.5 and if you open file location of that link you will see python 3.5 executable file just right next to it

Comment: @VivekSingh But how do I open that link ?

Comment: @Emerdan you need to add python3 to pycharm , when create a new project in pycharm it asks for the interpreter you can select which version you want to use